# Serializing JSON data in PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, serialization

I have a User table that has serialized data in one of the tables.

When the user logs in, that row for the user gets loaded into a session object. The issue is that the entire user object is then serialized by CI's Session library. This causes issues when unserializing. Digging down into the Session.php library, it looks like `unserialize` returns false.

Has anyone come across this or know of any way to better serialize serialized objects?

**EDIT**
Correct, it's not serialized in my User table. It's saved as JSON. Which still breaks the unserialize

Comment: The better is just not serialize objects ever

Comment: Why not just store the user data in a session and let CI handle both the database contact and serialization?

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't be serialized in the first place.. but I'm inheriting this project and it is serialized. So what to do about it?

Comment: Saved in Json? try json_decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you data is saved as in json format then to bring it back to life (usable form) you should use `json_decode` function